# Are the ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem and ssl-cert-snakeoil.key unique per installation?

Tags: apache2, ssl, https, mod-ssl

Is my understanding that Apache2

> ... default HTTPS configuration will use a certificate and key
>   generated by the ssl-cert package.

That mean that the files *`ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem`* and *`ssl-cert-snakeoil.key`* are unique per each *ssl-cert* installation? Where is the script that generates them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are created by in the post-installation script of the `ssl-cert` package (`/var/lib/dpkg/info/ssl-cert.postinst`) by calling [make-ssl-cert](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/make-ssl-cert.8.html):

```
make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil
```